# Resharper 9 alternate folder namespace provider

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, namespaces, resharper, resharper-9.0

I am using Resharper which automatically recommends namespaces. I have a folder in my solution called `_T.E.S.T`, and I would like it to contribute to the namespace of all classes inside that folder. However, R#9 will see this folder as 4 separate namespaces (`_T`, `E`, `S`, `T`).

`using MyCompany._T.E.S.T.Core.Domain.Users` seems kinda silly.

Wat I would like to have Resharper suggest is the following: `MyCompany.Test.Core.Domain.Users`.

I was hoping if there was a setting for every folder in which I can specify an alternate namespace name, so that my `_T.E.S.T` folder would be picked up as `Test`. Is there such a possibility?

---

Please keep in mind that I'm using an example here. I know I could easily change the actual folder name, or disable Resharper's suggestion feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand completely, sorry, but there's no ability in ReSharper to do the exact thing you're asking. Meaning, to intelligently provide namespace alternatives based on pattern changes - i.e. so that your _T.E.S.T folder would be picked up as Test.  Might be a nice feature.